# How to use TinyMCE 4.5 with the WYSIWYG module?

Tags: wysiwyg

I am using the WYSIWYG module on Drupal 7, but the only TinyMCE editor I can use is version 3.5. I would like to use the version found [here](http://download.ephox.com/tinymce/community/tinymce_4.5.1_dev.zip?_ga=1.230257818.781462067.1478895187). How can I install this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous version of the WYSIWYG module didn't support TinyMCE, but it does now.